# What is the equivalent of the Java BigDecimal class in IOS

Tags: java, ios, iphone, bigdecimal

I have a request model class in server with BigDecimal Properties. While using the same in IOS Client application,What data type i should use? I tried with double,float,NSnumber,NSDecimalNumber but nothing works. Exception is raised in server while i'm using the above datatypes. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try NSDecimal instead of NSDecimalNumber

Comment: @Sudeepgeorge usually when trying to discover what an exception means, one must see the exception in full. Please elaborate; exactly what exception occurs? Can you post the stack trace?